# NetLogo GIS: Error Message Loading Shapefile

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile

I am receiving the following error message below when using the NetLogo GIS extension:

```
Extension exception: shapefile Data1/Hough.shp not found
error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'
```

My shape file is loaded in the same folder as my script. Can someone help me trouble shoot this issue?

-Ivory

I made sure my shape file is in the same folder as my script.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the error you get when you have misspelled something or the file address is not well written.

- If your Shapefile is in the same folder as your model, then maybe you need to use just  `set my-map gis:load-dataset "Hough.shp`
- In case you have your Shapefile in its own folder, contained in Data1, then it could be `set my-map gis:load-dataset "Data1/Hough/Hough.shp`

Hope this can help you. Next time, make sure you add in your question the part of the code giving you problems, it is way easier to help you knowing what you have coded to get that error!

Comment: Thank you, you were correct.  My script was already in the same folder as the data so I just needed to use the code set my-map gas:load-dataset "Hough.shp"